# Combining color_bar(...) and percent(...) in R formattable

Tags: r, formattable

I'm trying to create a color_bar where the bars are based on the percentage of a subset of row values i.e. a1=(a1+b1)/2. However, I also want the numbers to be formatted as percent.

I have tried googling but can't find anyone else having a similar problem. I suspect there might be a better way of doing this that is easier but I can't figure it out.

```
tempDf = data.frame(a=c(0.8,0.5), b=c(0.2,0.5),c=c(500,500)) # dummy data
formattable(tempDf,unlist(list(
  lapply(as.list(1:nrow(tempDf)), function(row) {
    list(
      area(row, 1:2) ~ color_bar('green', function(row) row/sum(row)), # creates the green bars which are based on the percentage a1=(a1+b1)/2
      area(row, 1:1) ~ function(x) percent(x, digits = 1) # formats the a row as percent *this overwrites the color bars*
      )
  })
)))
```

Expected output is that the green bars are visible in the A column as well as being in percent. Currently the percent code overwrites the bars.

Comment: Same issue, but it doesn't appear to affect the person writing this guide:
https://www.displayr.com/formattable/?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 2):

I did this using the `tidyverse`, but it works like a charm.  There's actually two portions to it, depending on what you need:

#### Percent formatting

This is assuming you have a variable which is coded between 0 and 1 already. Let's call it `pct_var`.

```
tempDf %>%
    mutate(pct_var = color_bar(colour_to_use)(formattable::percent(pct_var))
```

#### Scaling the bar between 0 and 1

This solution came from a [DisplayR blog post](https://www.displayr.com/formattable/) and requires you to write a pretty simple function (likely not a very useful one in other contexts).

```
perc_scale = function(x) (x/1)

tempDf %>%
    mutate(pct_var = color_bar(colour_to_use, fun = perc_scale)(formattable::percent(pct_var))
```

And there you have it, hope it's useful to someone.