# Formatting data in a table as percentage

Tags: r, kableextra, formattable

I have a dataframe that looks like this:[image: My data frame]

Here's the code to create this DF:

```
structure(list(ethnicity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("AS", 
"BL", "HI", "Others", "WH", "Total"), class = "factor"), `Strongly agree` = c(30.7, 
26.2, 37.4, 31.6), Agree = c(43.9, 34.5, 41, 45.4), `Neither agree nor disagree` = c(9.4, 
14.3, 8.6, 8.7), Disagree = c(10, 15.5, 9.9, 9.7), `Strongly disagree` = c(6, 
9.5, 3.2, 4.6)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to add data bars and makes these numbers as percentages. I tried using the formattable library to do that (see my code below).

```
formattable(df,align=c("l","l","l","l","l","l"),
        list(`ethnicity` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey", font.weight = "bold"))
            ,area(col = 2:6) ~ function(x) percent(x / 100, digits = 0)
            ,area(col = 2:6) ~ color_bar("#DeF7E9")))
```

I'm facing 2 problems:

1. The numbers don't appear as a percentage in the table output.
2. The alignment seems off in the last column i.e

Would really appreciate if someone could help me understand what am I missing here ?

[image]

Comment: If you can show the `dput` of the example, it would be easier to test

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I've edited the question so that its more clear

Comment: Got it, I've added that too.

Comment: For me the numbers are getting as percentages using the same script.  Can you try installing the devel version from `github` and check

Comment: This works for one column `df %>% 
  mutate(Agree = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(Agree/100))) %>% 
  formattable()`, I struggle to make it work with `mutate_at()`. The idea comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275279/combining-color-bar-and-percent-in-r-formattable)

Comment: you are right, i tried running this in a different environment and it worked. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution but it require a lot of typing, I guess it is possible to use `mutate_at()` but I just can't find out how to pass column names in the `percent()` part. Using the `.` produces an error.

This works with a lot of typing:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)

df %>% 
  mutate(`Strongly agree` = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(`Strongly agree`/100))) %>% 
  mutate(`Agree` = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(`Agree`/100))) %>% 
  mutate(`Disagree` = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(`Disagree`/100))) %>%
  mutate(`Neither agree nor disagree` = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(`Neither agree nor disagree`/100))) %>%
  mutate(`Strongly disagree` = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(`Strongly disagree`/100))) %>%
  formattable(.,
              align=c("l","l","l","l","l","l"),
              `ethnicity` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey", font.weight = "bold")))
```

This does not work but might be improved:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = 2:6, .funs = color_bar("#DeF7E9")(formattable::percent(./100))) %>% 
  formattable(...)
```

[Some more informations about this "strange" structure `var = color_bar(...)(var)`](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/use_kableExtra_with_formattable.html)